# React fetch results in Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch the results from an API call, store it in a state, and then print it. The results from the fetch print properly in the console... but the browser throws the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


class NorthAmerica extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {jsonData: ""};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.display);
        var map = new jvm.Map({
            container: jQuery(el),
            map: 'north_america_mill',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            hoverColor: true,
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#245b87'
                },
                hover: {
                    fill: "#76c4ea"
                }
            },
            onRegionClick:function(event, code){
                var name = map.getRegionName(code);
                fetch('http://localhost:8080/Search/SearchRestaurants?'
                    + 'searchTerm=' + name + '&location=' + 'toronto').then(response => {
                    if(response.ok){
                        response.json().then(json => {
                            this.setState({jsonData: JSON.parse(json)});
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        this.setState({jsonData: ""});
                    }
                });
            }

        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button id="back"><Link to="/discover" style={{display: 'block', height: '100%'}}/></button>
                <h1 id="discover_header">/ NORTH AMERICA</h1>
                <div id="map" ref={display => this.display = display} style={{width: '1000px', height: '700px'}}/>
                <p> JSON: {this.state.jsonData}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export class northAmerica extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<NorthAmerica/>);
    }
}
```

The code runs, but when I open it in the browser, I get the following error in the console:

```
:8080/NorthAmerica:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Very new to react, javascript and all that, so any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT:

The console returns this:

```
Querying https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=Canada&location=toronto&limit=3&cc=CA ...
{"region": {"span": {"latitude_delta": 0.006146690000008448, "longitude_delta": 0.014174379999985831}, "center": {"latitude": 43.653332250000005, "longitude": -79.3769827}}, "total": 7869, "businesses": [{"is_claimed": false, "rating": 2.0, "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.ca/biz/canada-post-toronto-16?adjust_creative=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA", "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/b561c24f8341/ico/stars/v1/stars_2.png", "review_count": 6, "name": "Canada Post", "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a6210baec261/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_2.png", "url": "https://www.yelp.ca/biz/canada-post-toronto-16?adjust_creative=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA", "categories": [["Post Offices", "postoffices"]], "phone": "4165060911", "snippet_text": "So I bookmarked this place in my mind when I came across it a few days ago running around the historical district maze because I had a lot of postcards I...", "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/b45HAZwX9Y7w_K754EQp6A/ms.jpg", "display_phone": "+1-416-506-0911", "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c00926ee5dcb/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_2.png", "id": "canada-post-toronto-16", "is_closed": false, "location": {"city": "Toronto", "display_address": ["595 Bay Street", "Downtown Core", "Toronto, ON M5G 2C2"], "geo_accuracy": 8.0, "neighborhoods": ["Downtown Core"], "postal_code": "M5G 2C2", "country_code": "CA", "address": ["595 Bay Street"], "coordinate": {"latitude": 43.6562119, "longitude": -79.3832626}, "state_code": "ON"}}, {"is_claimed": false, "rating": 3.5, "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.ca/biz/canada-post-toronto-5?adjust_creative=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA", "rating_img_url": "https://s                                                                        3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/5ef3eb3cb162/ico/stars/v1/stars_3_half.png", "review_count": 7, "name": "Canada Post", "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/2e909d5d3536/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_3_half.png", "url": "https://www.yelp.ca/biz/canada-post-toronto-5?adjust_creative=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA", "categories": [["Post Offices", "postoffices"]], "phone": "4162142352", "snippet_text": "Although it took me two tries before I actually got to send out my mail.. The first time i went at prime time lunch hour and there were probably 10 people...", "image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/UDknxp5yEtbG23fcb7ktXg/ms.jpg", "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/liY7MzZA_SegCa1hUzwlTg/ms.jpg", "display_phone": "+1-416-214-2352", "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/bd9b7a815d1b/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_3_half.png", "id": "canada-post-toronto-5", "is_closed": false, "location": {"city": "Toronto", "display_address": ["119 Spadina Avenue", "Downtown Core", "Toronto, ON M5C 1J4"], "geo_accuracy": 9.5, "neighborhoods": ["Downtown Core"], "postal_code": "M5C 1J4", "country_code": "CA", "address": ["119 Spadina Avenue"], "coordinate": {"latitude": 43.6505383, "longitude": -79.3770895}, "state_code": "ON"}}, {"is_claimed": false, "rating": 4.5, "mobile_url": "https://m.yelp.ca/biz/canada-post-toronto-8?adjust_creative=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA", "rating_img_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png", "review_count": 2, "name": "Canada Post", "rating_img_url_small": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png", "url": "https://www.yelp.ca/biz/canada-post-toronto-8?adjust_creative=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA\u0026utm_campaign=yelp_api\u0026utm_medium=api_v2_search\u0026utm_source=xemf3Y2VeAFbwwCWCR1xBA", "categories": [["Post Offices", "postoffices"]], "phone": "4168651833", "snippet_text": "Really love this little place, usually a visit to the post office is an experience I dread as it's usually a test of patience with unhappy surely service...", "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/9pw64sWPH67LF3mb38jQaA/ms.jpg", "snippet_image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/XhqdU7p7bfdrzq9b9yVv7g/ms.jpg", "display_phone": "+1-416-865-1833", "rating_img_url_large": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png", "id": "canada-post-toronto-8", "is_closed": false, "location": {"city": "Toronto", "display_address": ["260 Adelaide Street E", "Corktown", "Toronto, ON M5A 1N1"], "geo_accuracy": 8.0, "neighborhoods": ["Corktown"], "postal_code": "M5A 1N1", "country_code": "CA", "address": ["260 Adelaide Street E"], "coordinate": {"latitude": 43.65191, "longitude": -79.3705}, "state_code": "ON"}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fetch` you don't need to `parse()` the response, the `json()` method  is somewhat of a shortcut of `JSON.parse()`. It's sufficient to do:

```
this.setState({ jsonData: json });
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this doesn't fix the error though :(

Comment: Then the JSON returned from the server is probably faulty, could you log it to the console before doing `setState` and post what it says?

Comment: Added it to the question... if that's what your asking for? haha sorry, I'm new.

Comment: All good. And this `Querying https://api.yelp...` is part of what the server returns? Or do you log that before somewhere else?

Comment: I don't log it no, unless the fetch method doesn't it automatically. There's a sample response on the API page: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
Doesn't look like that querying... is returned.

Comment: Then the issue is possibly that text being added on top of the file by the server. Seems like you have control over that, maybe try to find where that comes from.